# How do I upload 4.5GB file to Oracle 12c database?

Tags: java

I have tired with 3.99GB file. It is working well, however when it reached to 4GB+ , it is not working. I am using spring Default Lob creator and jdbc template. Is there anything I can do to upload the large file.
1. I do not see any error. 
2. It executive the statement but only upload null or 300MB chunk

Comment: Databases are not made to store huge files. Store them on disk/cloud and keep a reference to the file in the DB.

Comment: I can understand that however in my usecase, the file should stay inside db

Comment: I would advice not to store it in the db, especially Oracle. If ACID is important, perhaps a second db (sql server with FILESTREAM support) to only store the files in an XA transaction would be an option. There are multiple reasons to say no to the current solution. Discuss it well with your management as it may cause bigger issues down the line.